# $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ and pull out property of conditional expectation without standard machine

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

This is gonna sound [dumb](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/) but here goes.

---

From David Williams' Probability with Martingales:

[image]

---

Incorrect proof:

$$\int_{\Omega} X d \mathbb P \int_{\Omega} Y d \mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} \underbrace{\int_{\Omega} XY d \mathbb P}_{a \ number} d \mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} XY d \mathbb P \int_{\Omega} (1) d \mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} XY d \mathbb P (1)$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} XY d \mathbb P $$

So what's wrong here? I guess:

1. The first step is nonsensical.
2. The first step is not nonsensical but wrong.
3. The first step is not nonsensical, right but at that point in the text, we don't know that we can do that. It may be explained in Chapter 8, but I'm not sure I can find exactly.

---

I think I can similarly prove $E[YX | \mathscr G] = YE[X|\mathscr G]$ without standard machine:

$E[X|\mathscr G]$ is any $\mathscr G$-measurable random variable $H$ s.t. $$\int_G H d \mathbb P =\int_G X d \mathbb P \tag{*}$$

$E[XY|\mathscr G]$ is any $\mathscr G$-measurable random variable $Z$ s.t. $$\int_G Z d \mathbb P =\int_G XY d \mathbb P$$

From $(*)$, I multiply $\int_G Y d \mathbb P$ on both sides:

$$\int_G Y d \mathbb P \int_G H d \mathbb P =\int_G Y d \mathbb P \int_G X d \mathbb P$$

$$\int_G  \int_G H Y d \mathbb P d \mathbb P =\int_G  \int_G X Y d \mathbb P d \mathbb P$$

$$\int_G H Y d \mathbb P  =  \int_G X Y d \mathbb P $$

$$\int_G H Y d \mathbb P  =  \int_G Z d \mathbb P $$

QED?

Okay now I sense something wrong here like if we could just manipulate Lebesgue integrals this way, then [everything would be equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Division_by_zero) or something. What exactly is wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is calling that function a number. Use dummy variables. $$\int_\Omega X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \int_\Omega Y(\nu)d\mathbb{P}(\nu) = \int_\Omega \int_\Omega X(\omega)Y(\nu)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\nu).$$ The term $$\int_\Omega X(\omega)Y(\nu)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$ is not a number but rather a function of $\nu$.

Comment: so, [similar to other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2694714/140308)?

Comment: I was more specific

Comment: Thanks mathworker21! ^-^